# SQL Query optimization for the following query

Tags: sql, netsuite

I created query to fetch data from database but when I used it on other roles it takes long time to load.

I am trying to optimize the following query.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ROWNUM AS RN,
      *
    FROM
      (        select
          t.closedate,
          CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'Accounts Receivable' ELSE 'Accounts Payable' End as Account,
          BUILTIN.DF(t.Entity) as Name,
          BUILTIN.DF(tl.subsidiary) as Subsidiary,
          t.Tranid AS SourceTransactionNumber,
          t.TranDate as SourceTransactionDate,
          CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'BILL' THEN 'BILL' WHEN t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'INVOICE' ELSE 'BILL PAYMENT' End as SourceTransactionType,
          ap.periodname AS UnrealizedGainPostingPeriod,
          CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
          AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
          AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END as BeginningFxRate,
          cr2.Exchangerate as EndFXRate,
          BUILTIN.DF(t.currency) as ForeignCurrency,
          Round(ForeignTotal, 2) as ForeignCurrencyBalance,
          Round(
            (
              (
                cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END
              ) * ForeignTotal
            ),
            2
          ) AS NetGainLoss,
          cexr.averagerate as ConsolidatedExchangeRate,
          Round(
            (
              (
                cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END
              ) * (ForeignTotal * cexr.averagerate)
            ),
            2
          ) AS ConsolidatedGainLoss,
        from
          Transaction t
          INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl ON (tl.Transaction = t.ID)
          AND (tl.MainLine = 'T')
          AND (
            (t.CloseDate IS NULL)
            OR (
              t.CloseDate >= TO_DATE('5/01/2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
            )
            AND (t.TranDate <= TO_DATE('5/31/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
          )
          INNER JOIN Subsidiary sb ON sb.id = tl.subsidiary
          INNER JOIN AccountingPeriod ap ON (
            (
              ap.id BETWEEN (298)
              AND (298)
            )
            AND ap.isposting = 'T'
          )
          INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr1 ON (
            cr1.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
            AND cr1.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
            AND cr1.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
          )
          INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr2 ON (
            cr2.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
            AND cr2.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
            AND cr2.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
          )
          INNER JOIN consolidatedexchangerate cexr ON (
            cexr.postingperiod = t.PostingPeriod
            AND cexr.fromsubsidiary = tl.subsidiary
            AND cexr.tosubsidiary = 1
          )
        Where
          (
          
            t.AbbrevType LIKE  ('%INV')
              OR t.AbbrevType LIKE ('%BILL')         
            
     
          AND 
            tl.subsidiary IN (
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5,
              6,
              7,
              10,
              11,
              12,
              13,
              19,
              21,
              30,
              32,
              33,
              34,
              35,
              39,
              42,
              49,
              52,
              55,
              63,
              64,
              65,
              66,
              68,
              8,
              9,
              15,
              16,
              31,
              36,
              37,
              41,
              43,
              47,
              48,
              54,
              56,
              57,
              58,
              59,
              69,
              70
            )
          )
            AND 
            t.CloseDate IS NULL
            OR 
              t.CloseDate >= TO_DATE('7/01/2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
            
            AND t.TranDate <= TO_DATE('7/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
         )
  )
WHERE
  (
    RN BETWEEN 1
    AND 5000
  )
```

The load it take is in the area

```
 AND 
            t.CloseDate IS NULL
            OR 
              t.CloseDate >= TO_DATE('7/01/2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
            
            AND t.TranDate <= TO_DATE('7/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I have found out that the date functionality in the query is taking more load to fetch the data.

Is there any other area were it can optimized?

Comment: firstly, best to also post each table row counts then available index

Comment: there are various ways to optimize query. there are excellent optimization tools available.

Comment: "I used 'IN' instead of 'OR' so it took some less time to load" - I guarantee doing this will not make any actual difference to the performance of the query (because `IN` and `OR` are just alternative syntaxes for the same underlying semantic operation). I'll bet that the query was faster the second-time around (with `IN`) simply because the RDBMS engine had rebuilt its `STATISTICS` in the time-between your experiments or because it had cached a good execution plan before it was evicted from the cache. Never speculate about SQL performance, instead _look at the execution plan_.

Comment: Anyway, **we cannot really help you without seeing your execution plan**. We need to know your `CREATE TABLE` definitions, we need to know your `INDEX`es on the table, and we need to other details besides.

Comment: This data is fetched from the NetSuite Product table.

Comment: [For more information, visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851171/sql-query-optimization-for-the-following-query-in-date-functionality)