# SQL Query optimization for the following query in Date functionality

Tags: sql, netsuite

I created query to fetch data from database but when I used it on other roles it takes long time to load.

I am trying to optimize the following query.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ROWNUM AS RN,
      *
    FROM
      (        select
          t.closedate,
          CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'Accounts Receivable' ELSE 'Accounts Payable' End as Account,
          BUILTIN.DF(t.Entity) as Name,
          BUILTIN.DF(tl.subsidiary) as Subsidiary,
          t.Tranid AS SourceTransactionNumber,
          t.TranDate as SourceTransactionDate,
          CASE when t.AbbrevType = 'BILL' THEN 'BILL' WHEN t.AbbrevType = 'INV' THEN 'INVOICE' ELSE 'BILL PAYMENT' End as SourceTransactionType,
          ap.periodname AS UnrealizedGainPostingPeriod,
          CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
          AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
          AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END as BeginningFxRate,
          cr2.Exchangerate as EndFXRate,
          BUILTIN.DF(t.currency) as ForeignCurrency,
          Round(ForeignTotal, 2) as ForeignCurrencyBalance,
          Round(
            (
              (
                cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END
              ) * ForeignTotal
            ),
            2
          ) AS NetGainLoss,
          cexr.averagerate as ConsolidatedExchangeRate,
          Round(
            (
              (
                cr2.Exchangerate - CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) >= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate WHEN (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'YYYY')) > (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'YYYY'))
                AND (TO_CHAR (t.TranDate, 'MM')) <= (TO_CHAR (ap.startdate, 'MM')) THEN t.exchangerate ELSE cr1.Exchangerate END
              ) * (ForeignTotal * cexr.averagerate)
            ),
            2
          ) AS ConsolidatedGainLoss,
        from
          Transaction t
          INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl ON (tl.Transaction = t.ID)
          AND (tl.MainLine = 'T')
          AND (
            (t.CloseDate IS NULL)
            OR (
              t.CloseDate >= TO_DATE('5/01/2019', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
            )
            AND (t.TranDate <= TO_DATE('5/31/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
          )
          INNER JOIN Subsidiary sb ON sb.id = tl.subsidiary
          INNER JOIN AccountingPeriod ap ON (
            (
              ap.id BETWEEN (298)
              AND (298)
            )
            AND ap.isposting = 'T'
          )
          INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr1 ON (
            cr1.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
            AND cr1.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
            AND cr1.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
          )
          INNER JOIN CurrencyRate cr2 ON (
            cr2.BaseCurrency = sb.currency
            AND cr2.TransactionCurrency = t.Currency
            AND cr2.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.enddate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
          )
          INNER JOIN consolidatedexchangerate cexr ON (
            cexr.postingperiod = t.PostingPeriod
            AND cexr.fromsubsidiary = tl.subsidiary
            AND cexr.tosubsidiary = 1
          )
        Where
          (
          
            t.AbbrevType LIKE  ('%INV')
              OR t.AbbrevType LIKE ('%BILL')         
            
     
          AND 
            tl.subsidiary IN (
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4,
              5,
              6,
              7,
              10,
              11,
              12,
              13,
              19,
              21,
              30,
              32,
              33,
              34,
              35,
              39,
              42,
              49,
              52,
              55,
              63,
              64,
              65,
              66,
              68,
              8,
              9,
              15,
              16,
              31,
              36,
              37,
              41,
              43,
              47,
              48,
              54,
              56,
              57,
              58,
              59,
              69,
              70
            )
          )
            AND 
            t.CloseDate IS NULL
            OR 
              t.CloseDate >= TO_DATE('7/01/2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
            
            AND t.TranDate <= TO_DATE('7/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
         )
  )
WHERE
  (
    RN BETWEEN 1
    AND 5000
  )
```

The load it take is in the area

```
 AND 
            t.CloseDate IS NULL
            OR 
              t.CloseDate >= TO_DATE('7/01/2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY')
            
            AND t.TranDate <= TO_DATE('7/31/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I have found out that the date functionality in the query is taking more load to fetch the data.

Is there any other area were it can optimized?

Comment: What is `p.startdate` ? a date, or a varchar ?

Comment: @wildplasser ap.startdate is a date

Comment: Then: `ND cr1.EffectiveDate = TO_DATE(ap.startdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` <<--- what is this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need those "tables" and "data" of yours to fully test and optimize this query, so I can just look at the query and explain to you the parts that negatively affect the performance there.

1. When you are using the "OR" in where clause, then DB can not use index fields. The table will be a full scan. This is a bad performance. You can use `UNION` instead of `OR`. For example:

   ```
    select * from products
    where price = 25 or price = 10;

    select * from products
    where price = 25 
    union all 
    select * from products
    where price = 10;
   ```
2. You are using OR in join condition too, it's very bad performance.
3. When two or three fields are always used in conditions, so creating one index for combining these fields gives high performance than creating a separate index for each field,
   For example:

   `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX products_name_idx ON products USING btree (name, price);`